# Why is there a import error when packagename equal filename?

Tags: python

I'm wondering why python has a problem when the packagename of the import statement is equal to the actual filename of the python script. Can you explain it deeply? It's always a stupid mistake. Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to import a package from itself? What for?

Comment: As far as i know package name and filename can be same!

Comment: I don't want to import a package from itself. It's just a bad naming of the file. Let's say you have a package with the name "youtube" and your python file has the same naming with the import statement "youtube". Why can't python handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i have understood your question correctly, you are asking how to handle package and module import if they have the same name. Suppose you have a module `foo.py` and a package `foo/`.

File `foo.py`:

```
print("foo module loaded")
```

File `foo/__init__.py`:

```
print("foo package loaded")
```

File `test1.py`:

```
import foo
```

File `test2.py`:

```
import os, imp

def import_module(dir, name):
    """ load a module (not a package) with a given name 
        from the specified directory 
    """
    for description in imp.get_suffixes():
        (suffix, mode, type) = description
        if not suffix.startswith('.py'): continue
        abs_path = os.path.join(dir, name + suffix)
        if not os.path.exists(abs_path): continue
        fh = open(abs_path)
        return imp.load_module(name, fh, abs_path, (description))

import_module('.', 'foo')
```

Now running the tests:

```
$ python test1.py 
foo package loaded

$ python test2.py 
foo module loaded
```