# ImportError: cannot import name 'Elasticsearch' from 'elasticsearch'

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pip

When I try to import Elasticsearch in python 3.5 to python 3.7 I get always the same Error.

#### Code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
print(Elasticsearch())
```

#### Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "elasticsearch.py", line 3, in <module>
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
  File "/app/elasticsearch.py", line 3, in <module>
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
ImportError: cannot import name 'Elasticsearch' from 'elasticsearch' (/app/elasticsearch.py)
```

#### The Error for Python 3.8

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "elasticsearch.py", line 1, in <module>
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
  File "/app/elasticsearch.py", line 1, in <module>
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
ImportError: cannot import name 'Elasticsearch' from partially initialized module 'elasticsearch' (most likely due to a circular import) (/app/elasticsearch.py)
```

I tried it with Ubuntu 18.04, Windows and Docker. For Docker I tried python:3.8 to python:3.5 also python:alpine-3.8 to python:alpine-3.5

#### As requirements I use:

```
elasticsearch==7.1.0
```

#### Searching for Elasticseach Package

```
pip show elasticsearch

Name: elasticsearch
Version: 7.1.0
Summary: Python client for Elasticsearch
Home-page: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py
Author: Honza Král, Nick Lang
Author-email: honza.kral@gmail.com, nick@nicklang.com
License: Apache License, Version 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: urllib3
Required-by:
PS
```

Also I tried to use elasticsearch version 6 & 5. But allways the same error. I'm quite confused...

Comment: I think your script name is elasticsearch.py ???...change the name file

Comment: Damn yeah this was my problem ‍♂ now it works, thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like I said above just rename your script elasticsearch.py to another ..

Answer (score 4):

Your filename should not be as same as the package name. By renaming the file the problem would be solved. For more information why this error happened you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40876193/why-is-there-a-import-error-when-packagename-equal-filename).

Example:

```
elasticsearch.py  ----rename-to---->  sth-else.py
```